# Questions about calculus

Tags: calculus

I want to find a $f (x)$ such that the convergence interval of the Taylor series of $f (x)$ is different from the convergence interval of the integrated function $(F (x))$.

Comment: A power series $\sum a_k x^k$  has a radius of convergence $r$ (this is the largest number $r$ such that, for $|x|<r$, the series converges. Apart from that, the Taylor series of a smooth function $f$ may converge, but to some function different than $f$. What do you now mean by convergence interval of the Taylor series? The radius of convergence, or the interval on which it converges to $f$?

Comment: And what is the 'convergence interval of the integral function'?

Comment: Is the radius of convergence

Comment: And convergence interval of the integral function is the convergence radius of the Taylor series after the function is integrated